# Angular *ngFor displaying keys and values in root but not sub data

Tags: angular

I have some data that looks like this:

```
data = {
    title: 'some title',
    name: 'some name',
    active: false,
    extra: [
        {
            title: 'some data'
        }
    ]
  };

And I've displaying the key and values using:

<ul class="list-group" *ngFor="let item of data | keyvalue">
    <li class="list-group-item">{{ item.key }}:{{ item.value }}</li>
</ul>
```

This problem is that it's not displaying the sub data for example,
the data in `extra: [];`

I just get Object

How can I fix this?

Comment: so you want to display the keys and their values. `extra` is a key, should this also be displayed? Can you also have nested objects as well? How deep can the nesting go? Infinitely deep?

Comment: The data goes up to 2 deep

Comment: how do you want to show the value of `extra`?

Comment: I'd like to show key and value of subs

Comment: In that case you need to loop through `extra` again within `*ngFor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of data | keyvalue">
    <li class="list-group-item" *ngIf="isNested(item.value)">
      {{ item.key }}
      <ul class="list-group">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let nestedVal of item.value">
          <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let nestedKeyVal of nestedVal | keyvalue">
            {{ nestedKeyVal.key }}: {{ nestedKeyVal.value }}
          </li>
        </ng-container>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item" *ngIf="!isNested(item.value)">
      {{ item.key }}:{{ item.value }}
    </li>
  </ng-container>
</ul>
```

where isNested can be as simple as this

```
isNested(value) {
  return typeof(value) === 'object';
}
```